# Most human-like teratoma ever recorded?

Tags: cancer, mutations

I'm curious to learn about the 'most human' teratoma ever recorded. By that I mean a teratoma which most resembles the form of a human being.

I suppose there are several factors which would contribute to this criteria:
-Most organs, and components found in a human (e.g. brain, teeth, organs, etc.)
-Most closely organized structurally like a developing human.

Also I was wondering. Given the right conditions could a teratoma grow into a living being? Could they theoretically develop the necessary organs to be excised from their host and sustain the functions necessary for survival.

Basically I am curious to learn about the possibility of teratoma maturing into a bonafide organism.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a 2003 paper published in the Journal of Korean Medical Science describing a case of a 'homunculus' within a teratoma: http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3055135/

It contained some hair, brain tissues, cranial and other bones, but no internal organs.

Comment: Way cool. This is the best example I've seen thus far. Thanks for bringing it up.